# Assuming hydrostatic pressure distribution despite fluid motion

Tags: fluid-statics

in some exam questions I've looked at it is stated that the pressure distribution is hydrostatic, even though there is fluid motion. (In these cases the velocity has been constant over the section where the pressure is said to vary hydrostatic). Is it really possible to assume that the pressure varies hydrostatically when there's fluid motion?

Comment: What do you mean by "distribution is hydrostatic"? Do you mean that pressure distribution is same as in case of a moving fluid?

Comment: I mean that the pressure is varying hydrostatically, i.e P(z) = P0 + rho*g*z.